# React Hooks - How to use a make a state dependent on another state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I recently started using hooks in react and I am often having this problem: I create a first big state which is used by all my component, but some of the smaller parts of my component divide this state and create their own state for simplicity.

For example

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const initialFilters = {
  name: "",
  code: ""
};

function Filter({ value, setFilters }) {
  const [tempValue, setTempValue] = useState(value);

  return (
    <input
      value={tempValue}
      onChange={e => setTempValue(e.target.value)}
      onBlur={() => setFilters(tempValue)}
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(initialFilters);
  const agents = [
    { name: "bob", code: "123" },
    { name: "burger", code: "3123" },
    { name: "sponge", code: "34" }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Name filter</label>
      <Filter
        value={filters.name}
        setFilters={value =>
          setFilters(filters => ({ ...filters, name: value }))
        }
      />
      <label>Code filter</label>
      <Filter
        value={filters.code}
        setFilters={value =>
          setFilters(filters => ({ ...filters, code: value }))
        }
      />
      <button onClick={() => setFilters(initialFilters)}>Reset filters</button>
      <ul>
        {agents
          .filter(
            agent =>
              agent.name.includes(filters.name) &&
              agent.code.includes(filters.code)
          )
          .map((agent, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              name: {agent.name} - code: {agent.code}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CodeSandox available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-jackson-ux6df)

In this example the filters work fine, but their value are not emptied when we use the button Reset.

The filters create their own states to dispatch new state only on blur, and still be controlled. I guess I could use ref here, but I use this example to showcase a simple case of state dependent on another state (and therefore on props).

How should I go about implementing this in an idiomatic React way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `useEffect` hook. The 1st argument is a function and the 2nd argument is an array of dependencies. When a dependency changes value, the function is executed again.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

// ....code removed....

  useEffect(() => {
    setTempValue(value);
  }, [value]);

// ....code removed....
```

Sandbox with changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bogdan-ljugv

Comment: Do note that if it's a custom hook, it might return old value at first, because useEffect callback will trigger after the component has hit the return statement.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable), your state is created on the first render only and only then it is equal to your initial value.
You could write a custom hook `useFilter` and expose your filter-reseter:

```
const useFilter = (value, setFilters) => {
  const [tempValue, setTempValue] = useState(value);
  const resetFilter = () => setTempValue(value)

  return {
      resetFilter,
      getInputProps: () => ({
          onChange: e => setTempValue(e.target.value),
          onBlur: () => setFilters(tempValue),
          value: tempValue,
      })
  }
```

and instead of doing:

```
      <Filter
        value={filters.name}
        setFilters={value =>
          setFilters(filters => ({ ...filters, name: value }))
        }
      />
```

do this:

```
const setFilters = value => setFilters(filters => ({ ...filters, name: value }))
const { resetTempFilter, getInputProps } = useFilter(value, setFilters)
...
<input {...getInputProps()} />
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I was wondering how to do this with a custom hook.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you much easier to re-instantiate children with changing `key` prop(so named ["reset state"](https://medium.com/@albertogasparin/forcing-state-reset-on-a-react-component-by-using-the-key-prop-14b36cd7448e) technique based on how [reconciliation works](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) in React):

```
const [resetKey, setResetKey] = useState(0);
const doReset = setResetKey(key => key + 1);

      <Filter
         key={`name-filter-${resetKey}`}
         ...
      />
      <Filter
         key={`code-filter-${resetKey}`}
         ...
      />
      <button onClick={doReset}>Reset!</button>
```

It's not only easier to achieve. It also will work the same for any stateful components you cannot modify(for any reason).